# Golang XML unmarshalling an array doesn't work

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

below is a simple example of the code I'm trying to unmarshal:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Entry struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"entry"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
}

type Directory struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"directory"`
    Count   string   `xml:"count,attr"`
    Entries []Entry
}

func main() {
    var (
        dir     Directory
        xmldata = `
                <directory count="2">
                    <entry name="file-1"/>
                    <entry name="new-file-2"/>
                </directory>
                `
    )
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmldata), &dir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Count : %v\n", dir.Count)

    // none entry found ???
    fmt.Printf("Length of entries: %d", len(dir.Entries))
    for _, e := range dir.Entries {
        fmt.Println("Entry: " + e.Name)
    }

}
```

The problem is that the array of entries is empty, no matter how many "entry" XML tags there are none that is unmarshalled.
When I filled the Directory object and Marshalled it into a string I've got something like this:

```
<directory count="4"><entry name="file-1"></entry><entry name="new-file-2"></entry></directory>
```

but when I put this again to unmarshal I've got only the count attribute of Directory object filled with 4 and none entries in the array.

Does anyone know where I have made a mistake that marshalling works fine but it is impossible to unmarshal it?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/2_MkIQwVmLu

Comment: thx a lot mkopriva